# Checking UPTIME of remote server in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to retrieve the UPTIME of a remote server using the below code snippet in my script.

```
$lastboottime = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName     $server -Credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime
$sysuptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime)
$uptime = "   UPTIME           :    $($sysuptime.days) Days, $($sysuptime.hours) Hours, $($sysuptime.minutes) Minutes, $($sysuptime.seconds) Seconds"
```

I get the below error when executing the script:

```
Exception calling "ToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: dmtfDate"
```

I am unable to determine what the error message is what arguments are required?

Thanks!

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` <-- that is a bad idea in this scenario and may even be your problem. You'll start trying to silently convert null values. You need that command to error if it failed, otherwise the rest will fail.

Comment: This code works fine. I agree with arco444. `$lastboottime` is most likely null when this fails. `ToDateTime($null)` does create that erorr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting a null from the first line. Like Arco444 shows in his comment you are telling the command that if it fails not to notify you and continue processing. If it does fail `$lastboottime` would be $null. You can get a similar error if you put in `$null` on purpose.

```
System.DirectoryServices.dll[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($null)
```

> System.DirectoryServices.dll[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime
>   : The term 
>   'System.DirectoryServices.dll[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,  or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + System.DirectoryServices.dll[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToD
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Director...er]::ToDateTime:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

A simple if will check for the presence of data in the variable. And the `$uptime` value will reflect that as well.

```
$lastboottime = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName     $server -Credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime
If($lastboottime){
    $sysuptime = (Get-Date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime)
    $uptime = "   UPTIME           :    $($sysuptime.days) Days, $($sysuptime.hours) Hours, $($sysuptime.minutes) Minutes, $($sysuptime.seconds) Seconds"
} Else {
    $uptime = "   UPTIME           : Unable to determine for host $server"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting time values on WMI-Objects to datetime-objects can be done by calling the method ConvertToDateTime on the object itself.

Simple example:

```
$wmi = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$lastboottime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.LastBootUpTime)
$sysuptime = (Get-Date) - $lastboottime
$uptime = "   UPTIME           :    $($sysuptime.days) Days, $($sysuptime.hours) Hours, $($sysuptime.minutes) Minutes, $($sysuptime.seconds) Seconds"
write-host $uptime
```

Comment: this should be the answer!